# Error Access denied for Localuser

Tags: php, admin, edit

trying to create an admin panel that has the ability to edit users. I have an edit user button that when clicked tells me the error, however I have made an account with all priviledges called admin with the password admin but it still tells me that there's a problem with localhost. Using XAmpp.

http://postimg.org/image/p8teaqdgp/
    ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mxwebsite'

Below is my editusers.php:

```
<?php
include 'adminpage.php';
include 'connection.php';
mysql_select_db( "mxwebsite" ) or die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>UserID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>D-O-B</th></tr>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$userid = $row['UserID'];
$firstname = $row['FirstName'];
$lastname = $row['LastName'];
$email = $row['Email'];
$dob = $row['DateofBirth'];
$username = $row['Username'];
$password = $row['Password'];

// Now for each looped row

echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$userid."</td><td style='width: 200px;'>".$firstname."</td><td>".$scale."</td><td>".$lastname."</td><td>".$email."</td></tr>".$dob."</td></tr>".$username."</td></tr>".$password."</td></tr>";

} // End our while loop
echo "</table>"

?>
```

And here is my connection.php:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mxwebsite') or exit;

?>
```

Comment: Your query is totally wrong. you're doing `select count(*)`, which would return **ONE** row of data. then you loop on that one row result and try to access a bunch of fields which don't exist because you didn't select them.

Comment: I meant to change it back, i did have it SELECT * FROM Users

Comment: well, the error is clear: You're not using the right mysql credentials.

Comment: But I mentioned I've made an account with priviledges and used them but it returns the same error saying it's localhost.

Comment: well, look at the error message`... user ''@...`. Your username isn't coming across, and you're calling mysqli_connect as root and no password. Something's screwy there, and using a root account with no password is a massive security hole. NEVER use a root account in web-facing code.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on line 3

sorry - this is the new error

Comment: ^ that error comes when using the admin credentials, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "using password: no"> Did you set a password on the root account, then you'd have to use that password.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ixvq17ogz/ here are my sql accounts

Comment: root:localhost:yes  - so yeah, there's a password and you're NOT providing it.

Comment: SQL user admin error: ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mxwebsite'

and when I use root the error is: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on line 3 sorry

Just realised I didn't make that clear at all haha sorry

Comment: Do you know the SQL to change the password for root? I don't remember setting one

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: Nevertheless, when I use the admin account with it's password and priviledges I get this error: ErrorAccess denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mxwebsite'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68420/discussion-between-uyyyfgfar-and-marc-b).